# .NET mvc adding more then 1 entity to db

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to add several entities to the db but I get this error:

"Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'Schema.Domain.DataModels.ActivitySummery' have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration."

```
public void CreateNewGeneratedSchema(List<WeekDayViewModel> weekDays, int userId)
    {
        List<ActivitySummery> savedActivities = _schemaRepository.GetAllActivitySummeries(userId).ToList();
        foreach(ActivitySummery activitySummery in savedActivities)
        {
            _schemaRepository.DeleteActivitySummery(activitySummery.ActivitySummeryId);
        }

        foreach (WeekDayViewModel weekDay in weekDays)
        {
            foreach (ActivitySummeryViewModel activitySummeryViewModel in weekDay.ActivitiySummeries)
            {
                try
                {
                    ActivitySummery activitySummery = new ActivitySummery()
                    {
                        ActivityId = activitySummeryViewModel.ActivityId,
                        WeekDayId = activitySummeryViewModel.WeekDayId,
                        //Change userId
                        UserId = 1,
                        StartTime = activitySummeryViewModel.StartTime,
                        EndTime = activitySummeryViewModel.EndTime,
                        ActivityDescription = activitySummeryViewModel.Description,
                        Activity = _schemaRepository.GetSpecificActivity(activitySummeryViewModel.ActivityId),
                        WeekDay = _schemaRepository.GetSpecificWeekDay(activitySummeryViewModel.WeekDayId)
                    };
                    _schemaRepository.CreateActivitySummery(activitySummery);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Something went wrong when trying to save the activity summery");
                }
            }
        }
        _schemaRepository.Save();
        _schemaRepository.Dispose();
    }
```

I know one solution that might work and it's to save and dispose the _schemaRepository after every time i added one model to the db and create a new instace of _schemaRepository. But im not sure if that is the right way. I know that every model that im trying to save has the pk of 0 and i think that might be the problem. However it still works and the db accepts the new entities but I still get the exception.

Comment: [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] just use the identity?

Comment: Im not using code first

Comment: do that with fleunt API then you do not have to care about the Id.

Answer (score 0):

If your model (which you didn't show) has the primary key as `ActivityId` (which you also didn't indicate) and it is setup to auto-generate the primary key:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ActivityId { get; set; }
```

Then you *must not* include the primary key in the `CreateActivitySummery` method (also which you haven't provided).

```
// Remove this line...
// ActivityId = activitySummary.ActivityId;
```

Do note that a (reasonable) alternative to having the database generate the primary key automatically is to use Guid/UniqueIdentifier without using `DatabaseGenerated`. Then your application code can use `Guid.NewGuid` to generate new (presumably unique) primary keys that it can insert with no problem and track related entities easily.